# WPF async in Current Dispatcher

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, dispatcher

I'm updating my WPF app from .net 4.6 Framework to .net 6.
For some reason I can't find the correct way to execute async code in the dispatcher.

```
private async Task HandleNotFromUI()
{
  await Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, SomeMethodAsync);
}
private async Task SomeMethodAsync()
{
   someCode();
   await someAsyncCode();
   someMoreCode();
}
```

And it "looses" the thread on await someAsyncCode and does not hit someMoreCode.
Similar code was working fine before updating to .net 6. Is it something about .net 6 or WPF in .net 6 or I'm making some mistake?

Comment: Show what threads individual lines of code run under. Specifically though, `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke` is relatively useless, since it queues up the work on the same thread that calls it. The only thing you get is the equivalent of `await Task.Yield();`

Comment: It's not clear how these two methods relate to each other. It's the second you say you have a problem with, but this doesn't' seem to involve the dispatcher at all. And what do you mean by 'it looses the thread'?

Comment: By "looses" I guess it is like using async void. It does not comes back to continue the excecution of the code below the line that awaits.

Comment: Are you sure it's not erroring in someAsyncCode() ? Put a try catch in that method around everything and debug the catch..

Comment: @Andy I did that already and it is not crashing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher to App.Current.Dispatcher and it is working. I'm not sure why though.